# Comma appearing in text box and popup calendar in google chrome in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, asp.net-ajax

I have a very strange problem. i have a text box and date picker inside an update panel and a button inside panel, when ever i enter some text in text box and select date and press "enter"
button event handel is called and after call back text box content copy and concate with "comma" same as the issue with date picker.
Any solution of this??

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlPickIt" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
                <Triggers>
                   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGo" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRcpnt" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRcpntDiffDate" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNewOrder" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPickZip" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnGo" meta:resourcekey="pnlPickZipResource">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pickItHeading">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" class="hdgPickIt enabledl">
                                <table><tr><td>
                                    <h2 style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="litDivStoreFinderMessage" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="litDivStoreFinderMessageResource"></asp:Literal>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkShowOtherCountries" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lnkShowOtherCountriesResource"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:Localize ID="lclOtherCoutriesText" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lclOtherCoutriesTextResource"></asp:Localize>
                                    </h2>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="button" id="btnAddressBook1" value='<%=Getlocalresourceobject("ResourceAddBook") %>' onclick="ShowAddressBook('<%= txtZip.ClientID %>', '<%= hdnContactID.ClientID %>', this, 'Right');" style='display: <%=IIF(Utility.Generic.IsID(CType(Session("UserSessionState"), BO.UserSessionState).UserID), "", "none") %>; width:131px; font-size:12px;' />
                                </td>
                                </tr></table>


                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 138px"><asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" onfocus="ZipVal=this.value;" onblur="this.value=fixZipAndPostalCode(this.value); $('[id^=dverr]').hide();ForcebtnGoClick(this.value);" CssClass="txtPickIt" Style="width: 100px" MaxLength="7" WaterMarkText='<%#GetLocalResourceObject("ZipPostalCodeWaterMarkText") %>' runat="server" meta:resourcekey="txtZipResource"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                <td style="width: 107px"><asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" onfocus="$('#dverr4').hide();" onblur="$('[id^=dverr]').hide();" CssClass="txtPickItCal" WaterMarkText='<%#GetLocalResourceObject("DateWaterMarkText") %>' Width="70px" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="txtDateResource"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                <td align="left" style="width: 55px"><asp:Button ID="btnGo" OnClientClick="$('#divZipNotFound').fadeOut();hideShipmentArrangements();HideZipFinder(); return ValidateZip();" onblur="$('#dverr4').hide();" CssClass="PickITGo" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnGoResource" /></td>
                                <td align="left" style="width:160px"><table><tr><td><a id="lnkStoreFinder" style="font-size:11px;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('hdnZipTextBoxID').value = '<%= txtZip.ClientID %>';ShowZipFinder(this, -367);return false;"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("lclFindResource.Text").ToString.Replace("**ZipCode**", GetZipCodeTextByCountry())%></a></td><td><asp:ImageButton id="btnGoBack" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# ImagePage & "bn/btn_goBackSmall.jpg" %>' /></td></tr></table></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div runat="server" visible="False" id="divZipState" style="position: absolute; font-size: 11px;height: 12px; color: #666666;"><asp:Literal ID="litZipState" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="litZipStateResource"></asp:Literal></div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <div id="dverr6" class="validatorMsgBig" style="position: absolute; display: none; height: 45px; width: 440px; padding: 5px;">
                        <a id="A6" href="#"><img id="img6" style="float: right; border-width: 0px;" onclick="return HideErrorMsg('dverr6');" src="<%= ImagePage %>btn_cross_l.jpg" /></a>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="<%= ImagePage %>icon_order_error_big_yelowbg.jpg" /></td>
                                <td align="left" style="padding-left: 10px;"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #383433;"><asp:Literal ID="litErrorMsg" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="litErrorMsgResource"></asp:Literal></span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?  Also, this doesn't happen in IE or Firefox?

Comment: yes this is not happening in firefox and IE. i am posting code in question